# How to delete rows with multiple conditions in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, conditional-statements, row

```
 import pandas as pd
 import numpy as np
 print df
```

I'm a newbie, I used pandas to process an excel file. I have a data frame like bellow

```
DAT_KEY      IP         DATA
01-04-19    10.0.0.1    3298329
01-04-19    10.0.0.1    0
02-04-19    10.0.0.1    3298339
02-04-19    10.0.0.1    0
01-04-19    10.0.0.2    3233233
01-04-19    10.0.0.2    0
01-04-19    10.0.0.3    0
```

I only want to delete the row when having same IP and `DAT_KEY` and `DATA=0`. Don't want to delete row have `DATA=0`, but DAT_KEY and IP unique.

My expected outcome:

```
DAT_KEY      IP         DATA
01-04-19    10.0.0.1    3298329
02-04-19    10.0.0.1    3298339
01-04-19    10.0.0.2    3233233
01-04-19    10.0.0.3    0
```

I try with drop duplicates but it not suitable with my case

```
df = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Comment: can there be duplicated `DAT_KEY` and `IP` with any other value except 0? and do you want to keep them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

- [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) -  function is used to split the data into groups based on some criteria.
- `.first()` -  Compute first of group values.

**Ex.**

```
df = df.groupby(['DAT_KEY','IP'],as_index=False,sort=False).first()
print(df)
```

**O/P:**

```
    DAT_KEY        IP     DATA
0  01-04-19  10.0.0.1  3298329
1  02-04-19  10.0.0.1  3298339
2  01-04-19  10.0.0.2  3233233
3  01-04-19  10.0.0.3        0
```

Comment: Sorry because i don't give full information. I have DAT_KEY of many days from 01-04 to 30-04. If use this `df = df.groupby('IP',as_index=False).first()`. Data remain to have only first row. of one day.

Comment: `df = df.groupby(['IP', 'DAT_KEY']as_index=False).first()
print(df)` it works thanks alots

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that's what you need:

```
    DAT_KEY        IP     DATA
0  01-04-19  10.0.0.1  3298329
1  01-04-19  10.0.0.1        0
2  02-04-19  10.0.0.1  3298339
3  02-04-19  10.0.0.1        0
4  01-04-19  10.0.0.2  3233233
5  01-04-19  10.0.0.2        0
6  01-04-19  10.0.0.3        0
7  01-04-19  10.0.0.1    99999

df.groupby(["DAT_KEY","IP"], as_index=False,sort=False).apply(lambda g: g if len(g)==1 else g[g["DATA"]!=0] ).reset_index(drop=True)                                                                                                      
Out[94]: 
    DAT_KEY        IP     DATA
0  01-04-19  10.0.0.1  3298329
1  01-04-19  10.0.0.1    99999
2  02-04-19  10.0.0.1  3298339
3  01-04-19  10.0.0.2  3233233
4  01-04-19  10.0.0.3        0
```